# Creating views for interactive matplotlib programatically

Tags: python, matplotlib

I recently discovered the interactive matplotlib figure which can be obtained in IPython/Jupyter by setting

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

I have a large time series in which I'm detecting events that I'd like to examine visually. I was hoping that rather than building a UI, I could simply hook in to the "Previous View"/"Next View" buttons in the interactive figure to move between the relevant regions in the data. The following doesn't work

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook

data = np.random.randn(1000000)
event1 = [0, 10]
event2 = [25, 40]
plt.plot(data)
plt.gca().set_xlim(event1) # pan to first event (this doesn't get stacked into the view)
plt.gca().set_xlim(event2) # pan to second event
```

Is there an easy way of programatically loading the interactive view list?